# Issue in the confirmation page icon, when joining a new community

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

When I'm trying to join a new community by clicking on the "Join this community" button on the non joined community, I'm receiving the following confirm page.

In that I'm seeing the description about the login account. There the icon for the Stack Exchange is displayed as Stack Overflow icon.

> [image: Confirm account]

When I checked with [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) in my edit user profile, the Stack Exchange account contains the Stack Exchange icon only.

> [image: My Login]

---

So it is a bug or the expected behaviour, or I'm overseeing that as an issue?